# How do you fill the parameters Class<? extends 'some class'>?

Tags: java, android

I was looking at some code online to help me with a problem and I found this interesting method (which fixed my problem) however it has these parameters

```
 public void showScene(Class<? extends AbstractScene> sceneClazz) {
```

After doing some research and using logic I figured out that it was just taking a class as a parameter that extends AbstractScene.... However, I want to know how to call this method again

I have tried multiple ways of calling it such as

```
showScene(new GameActivity());
showScene(GameActivity<? extends AbstractScene>());
```

but none of these work... How do I call this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a class literal, for instance:

```
showScene(GameActivity.class);
```

Any type of class that extends (or implements) `AbstractScene` will work.